# Generate a random 62500 digit number from any 62499 digit number and below?

Tags: calculus

Using a starting point starting from 0, 1, 2… how can we generate a unique, reproducible (and seemingly random) 62500 digit number until all of the possible 62500 digit numbers are used up

Comment: I think what you want is a [Random Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation).  If you want an explicit enumeration of the permutations, see [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Have you looked into any of the vast literature on [random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)? If not, then please do. Come back to MSE if you still can't find what you are looking for or need help with any of the references.